# How to save data when I delete a row or id?

Tags: laravel

My form is like this I have four row in database

[image: second]

May admin delete 2 rows or id.

[image: first]

How to save it

```
public function important_store(SettingRequest $request)
{
    $importants = collect([]);
    if ($request->importants) {
        foreach ($request->helps as $help) {
            $model = Important::updateOrCreate([
                'title' => $help['title']
            ], [
                'link' => $help['link']
            ]);
            $importants->push($model);
        }
    }
    Help::whereNotIn('id', $importants->pluck('id'))->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: you can use `Soft delete`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: You actually want to update your form, not delete it.https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-7x-dynamically-add-more-input-fields-using-handlebars-js

Comment: This is not an appropriate approach. Instead, you can make an ajax request to delete or soft_delete a record when the delete button is clicked.